# how to find the model precision Faster_rcnn_inception_v2?

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, eval, object-detection-api

please help .

run eval.py of the tensorflow detection model

I want to find the precision and I got this data.
Can someone explain to me if it's ok or not and what can I do please.

I am new in these subjects

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuKOO.png)

Answer (score 1):

To explain the concepts in detail.

1. For object detection instead of precision **Average precision** is considered.
2. **AP (Average Precision)** is a popular metric in measuring the accuracy of object detectors.
3. Average precision computes the average precision value for recall value over 0 to 1.

So what you need to do in your case is to create a **DataFrame** with `Objects, Actual value and Prediction value`, the prediction you can say TRUE if your **IoU** value >=0.5.

IoU measures the overlap between 2 boundaries. We use that to measure how much our predicted boundary overlaps with the ground truth (the real object boundary). In some datasets, we predefine an IoU threshold (say 0.5) in classifying whether the prediction is a true positive or a false positive.

[image]

Then you can calculate the average precision accordingly.

Hope this answer helps you, Happy Learning!

Comment: @Luiggi - Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.